# why a pair is not correctly being created - C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have the following declaration in `Key.h`

```
typedef uint64_t KeyHash;
```

and in my `Finder` class, I have a `C++` map declared as following:

```
std::map<std::pair<uint64_t, KeyHash>, Foo> table;
```

Therefore, I'm trying to create a new pair. The `Foo` object has two fields, `startKeyHash` and `foo_id`, both of the type `uint64_t`:

```
std::pair<uint64_t, KeyHash> key (foo.foo_id,
                                  foo.start_key_hash());
table[key] = tablet;
```

function `uint64_t Foo:start_key_hash()` returns the `startKeyHash`.
However, when I compile my code, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<long unsigned int, long unsigned int>::pair(<unresolved overloaded function type>, google::protobuf::uint64)’
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-`linux/4.4.6/../../../../include/c++/4.4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:111: note:
 candidates are: std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(_U1&&, _Arg0&&, _Args&& ...) [with _U1 =
 google::protobuf::uint64, _Args = , _T1 = long unsigned int, _T2 = long unsigned int]`
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the code you're bringing in from Google defines a `uint64` type, and somewhere you've accidentally used that instead of `uint64_t`. Note the `_t` is missing.

Comment: that's true ... should I cast from `uint64` to `uint64_t` ?